# В laravel появилась следующая ошибка SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown col

Tags: php, laravel

Я сделал связь между двумя таблицами "один к одному". Пытаюсь получить значение связанной таблицы, но выходит ошибка:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'wards.santa_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `wards` where `wards`.`santa_id` = 1 and `wards`.`santa_id` is not null limit 1)

```php
//Router
Route::get('/', function () {
    $santa = App\Models\Santa::all();
    foreach($santa as $row){
        echo "$row".'<br>';
        foreach($row->wards as $ward)
        {
            echo $ward['name'];
        }
    }
});
```

Миграции

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('santas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('ward_id')->nullable();
         $table->foreign('ward_id')->references('id')->on('wards')->nullOnDelete();
            $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('wards', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Модель SANTA:

```php
class Santa extends Model
{
   use HasFactory;
    public function wards()
    {
       return $this->hasOne(Ward::class);
    }
}
```

Буду рад любой помощи)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в модели `Santa` определен родитель из модели `Ward`. Правильно будет так:

```
class Santa extends Model
{
    public function ward()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo(Ward::class);
    }
}
```

А уже в `Ward` если хотите, можете определить `HasOne`:

```
class Ward extends Model
{
    public function santa()
    {
       return $this->hasOne(Santa::class);
    }
}
```

Т.к. отношение один-к-одному, вам не нужен второй foreach для вывода:

```
$santa = App\Models\Santa::all();
foreach($santa as $row){
    echo $row->ward->name;
}
```